# Adding an extra dimension to text classification

Tags: tensorflow, neural-network, recurrent-neural-network, text-classification, tensor

I want to do text classification using a neural network in Keras. I have setup a simple test sample using the following network:

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(Embedding(NUMVOCABOLARYWORDS, 5, input_length = sequenceDataPadded.shape[1]))
model.add(LSTM(256, dropout=0.2, recurrent_dropout=0.2))
model.add(Dense(128))
model.add(Dense(1))
```

This network accepts tokenized padded sequences of text. E.g. I tokenize the text "hello world" = [0,1,0,0,0..]. It train & evaluates fine.

Now my issue is that I do not want to enter a single sequence into the network, but rather a collection (let's say 500) sequences into the network and get a category out. So instead of an input with shape (100) it's now (500, 100). I'm unsure how to best create the network architecture, ie:

1) Should I flatten the input or try to reduce the dimensions? What layers could I use for that job?

2) Should I just create one large sequence with all the text?

3) Does it even make sense to have a LSTM with 4 dimensions?

4) Does examples exist for classification with an array of array of tokens?

The text is collected text from different sources, so the different sequences in each batch is not necessarily related in relation to anything else than date.

Comment: I'm thinking about merging all text for a given batch and input the tokenized text and frequencies, like [0, 1, 2, 5, 6, 4, 3...] [1, 2, 4, 5, 6, 7...], but I would really like some suggestions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think that merging all text together is the solution. The problem then is that if you feed it to the LSTM it that the hidden states of every text does not start initially. So you feed in the first text, and then the second and all other texts will have the current hidden state.

You could use the functional API and create different inputs and give each input its own LSTM. Then you can merge them and have the dense layers at the end.
Another thing that you could try is to use CNN. Again you'd either have to create multiple inputs or concatenate all the inputs and then use CNN layers. The advantage here could be the speed. Because depending on how many LSTMs you have and how big your input is training can take quite a while. Especially because the backpropagation also has to go through every timestep. So performance wise you may be better off with CNNs.

So what I would do is to keep the arrays separately with a max length. Then you pad every array to this length (if they are to short). Then you create multiple inputs with the [Functional API](https://keras.io/getting-started/functional-api-guide/) and use Conv1D Layers behind it. You do some conv operations (maybe stack a few conv layers, maxpooling, etc.). Then you merge them with the [concatenate layer](https://keras.io/layers/merge/). And then you have some more dense or CNN.

Comment: Hi Syrius.

Thank you for the input. 

If I understand you correctly, you would use CNN to improve the speed, and not for dimension reduction. I get that CNN's have their use in images, but I find they are a little more vague for tokenized input. E.g. if each integer in the array [1,2,6,4,7] represent a word, would it make sense to apply a kernel multiplying the inputs? Maybe that way I'm thinking about it is wrong.

Anyway, I'll do some testing :-)

Comment: CNN's are actually also used for NLP tasks quite a lot lately. Here are some blogposts and github repos: https://medium.com/jatana/report-on-text-classification-using-cnn-rnn-han-f0e887214d5f https://github.com/bhaveshoswal/CNN-text-classification-keras http://www.davidsbatista.net/blog/2018/03/31/SentenceClassificationConvNets/ You can also still use an embedding layer upfront, which may increase the performance. This would maybe also help the filters (kernels) as similar words should be projected into similar spaces.